# How to get the values only if all the keys have matched?

Tags: php, regex

I want to make a method that returns keys and values. But only if the keys include the following string "**_1**" and "**__last**".
If only one matches then exit the function, **only if the two string are included** in the key, return the key with the value for a weather.

```
$infoList = array("_key_1"=>array("time"=>9, "day"=>"Tuesday", "weather"=>"sunny", 
                                "humidity"=>"80%"),
                  "_key_2"=>array("time"=>5, "day"=>"Tuesday", "weather"=>"cloudy"),
                  "_key__last"=>array("time"=>3, "day"=>"Sunday", "weather"=>"rainy"))

public function getData() {
 $list = array();
 foreach($infoList as $key){
   if(preg_match('/(_key)_(_1)/', $key) && preg_match('/(_key)_(__last)/', $key) == TRUE){
     $list[$key] = $list[$key]["weather"] 
   } 

 }
 return $list

}
```

Comment: For your information, `if (something == TRUE)` is redundant, you can just write `if (something)`

Comment: if you want to check for `_1` and `_last`, why are you checking for `_key`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making your life so much more difficult that it need be, use `str_contains()` its easier than building complex REGEX's and getting very confused by the look of it :)

> I also fixed a number of other mistakes, such as the foreach that was not going to work, so check all the code.
> It is also better to pass data to a function/method otherwise you get into scoping issues!

```
$infoList = array("_key_1"=>array("time"=>9, "day"=>"Tuesday", "weather"=>"sunny", "humidity"=>"80%"),
                  "_key_2"=>array("time"=>5, "day"=>"Tuesday", "weather"=>"cloudy"),
                  "_key__last"=>array("time"=>3, "day"=>"Sunday", "weather"=>"rainy"));
                  
function getData(Array $infoList) {
    $list = [];
    $found = 0;
    foreach($infoList as $key => $val) {
        if( str_contains($key, '_1') || str_contains($key, '__last') ) {

            $list[$key] = $val["weather"];
            $found++;
        }
    }
    if ( $found >= 2 ) {
        return $list;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

$res = getData($infoList);
if ( $res !== false ){
    print_r($res);
} else {
    echo 'Not Found';
}
```

RESULTS

```
Array
(
    [_key_1] => sunny
    [_key__last] => rainy
)
```

Comment: Thank you!    
One question.If there’s another $infoList say $infoList2  that only contains _1, it will print out right? I only want to print it if both _1 and __last are included. How can I do that?

Comment: So you want to check all the array keys to make sure both keys exist before putting the weather data into the new array?

Comment: Yes. I only want the weather data when both keys exist.

Comment: I have amended the code, a simple count should make this possible

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with RegEx, you can use positive lookaheads, the same way you check for passwords characters :

```
<?php
$pattern = '/^(?=.*_1)(?=.*_last).*$/';

$shouldMatch = [
    '_1_last',
    'foo_1bar_lasthello',
    '_last_1',
    'foo_lastbar_1hello'
];

echo 'next ones should match : ' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($shouldMatch as $item)
{
    if (preg_match($pattern, $item))
        echo $item . PHP_EOL;
}

$shouldNOTMatch = [
    '_2_first',
    'bar_lasthello',
    'foo_las_1hello'
];

echo 'next ones should NOT match : ' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($shouldNOTMatch as $item)
{
    //  v------------ check
    if (!preg_match($pattern, $item))
        echo $item . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output :

```
next ones should match : 
_1_last
foo_1bar_lasthello
_last_1
foo_lastbar_1hello
next ones should NOT match : 
_2_first
bar_lasthello
foo_las_1hello
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. In $shouldMatch you have both "_1" and "_last" in one key but what I want is to search for the both "_1" and "_last" when these are in separate keys but same array.

Comment: @May so, *""_1" and "_last""* should in fact be *""_1" **or** "_last""* ?